# Node.js REST with Sockets

Tags: node.js, rest, sockets, socket.io, sockjs

The problem I am trying to solve is

- client makes a restful POST to node server.
- node server communicates with another external server via socket.
- when the socket response comes back from the other server - node server responds to client with the data received.

I can communicate to the client via REST and separately I can communicate to the external server via socket (response time is ~100ms).  But combining these results yields nothing.

```
const sjsc = require('sockjs-client');
app.post('/form', function(req, res) {
    const srvc = sjsc('http://external.server:port/path');
    srvc.onopen = function () {
        srvc.send(testData);
    }

    srvc.onmessage = function(data) {
        console.log('received ', data);
        res.send(data);
    };
});
```

Comment: Does your `srvc.onmessage` handler run at all?

Comment: not when combined using app.post.  if i remove everything associated with the server (app) and run it using just sjsc and node - it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

`const srvc = sjsc('http://external.server:port/path');`

this needed to be a `let`.  this is the only thing i changed and works perfectly.

`let srvc = sjsc('http://external.server:port/path');`